# is File facade deprecated in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: file, laravel, upload, storage

I just started to work with image uploads and stuff and was looking for the method to create a directory in the public folder. Now looking for the makeDirectory method in Laravel 5.1 docs I can see it refers it to 'Storage' , so is now Storage used instead of File? or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `File::` and `Storage::` facades to create a directory. I don't think it's depricated, becuase there is not such info in [5.3 deprecation list](https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade).

Comment: I'm not sure, I'd go with `Storage::`

Comment: Probably but for some reason Storage:: is not working locally, it doesn't create any directory while File:: does

Comment: `Storage::` works locally, it creates directory in `/storage/app` while `File::` creates directory in a `/public` directory.